# Assuming a coaxial cable is matched with the load antenna, what is the DC voltage at the entrance of the cable if the length of it goes to infinity

Tags: rf

This is a question from a previous year's exam which I'm having difficulties solving.

Given a load impedance of Zl = 48-i14 [ohm], we want to plan our coaxial cable with an impedance that gives a minimum SWR.

I understand that the min VSWR is 1 when there is no reflection and Vmin = Vmax, so the coaxial cable impedance has to match that of the load.

Now, the question states:

"If you take a voltmeter on DC, and attach it at the entrance of the coaxial cable to the inner conductor, and to the outer shielding, what will you read on the DVM if the length of the line tends to infinity?"

Now my attempt is this:

Since we're dealing with DC, we know that the DC resistance of a conductor increases linearly with the length of the line, which means we have infinite resistance, meaning all the voltage will fall on the line and not the antenna.

The second part asks what happens if we were to remove the load.

This is the same as asking what if Zl =infinity, which means that we should be getting max voltage on the load.

Somehow neither of these answers are sitting well with me, and I'd appreciate some input

Comment: depends on the initial charge.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make much sense. If the transmission line is infinitely long, why does it matter what's connected at the other end?

But in any case, an infinite transmission line is equivalent to a resistor. What do you get when you put a voltmeter across a resistor?

Comment: You get the voltage drop across it, V=IR. Why is an infinite transmission line equivalent to a resistor?

Comment: *"You get the voltage drop across it, V=IR."* But what is supplying DC current to your transmission line? *"Why is an infinite transmission line equivalent to a resistor?"* It's implicit in the definition of the "characteristic impedance" of the transmission line. A transmission line of **any** length terminated by a resistor \$R = Z_0\$ is indistinguishable from just the resistor itself.